# Load iframe inside an app with webpack potential memory leak

Tags: javascript, iframe, webpack, memory-leaks

I have an application. I load and unload an iframe in it and there is a 2MB memory leak for each load+unload.

When recording memory in chrome dev tools and comparing before and after the iframe, I don't see any familiar objects. All I see is (system), (array) and some more stuff with breakets.

I tried to inverstigate it and it seems like some objects are hold by webpack.
Is the any thing I should be aware of when loading/unloading iframe in an application which uses webpack?